# read userinput with fixed first characters?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

this is my first post in on this platform. Ive found so much helpful tips. I want to thank everyone who is using this platform active.

My question is:
How can I use the reader input in bash with fixed first characters?

For example

```
read -p "Enter a username:" bb-d-USERNAME
```

so the **bb-d-** is already given. The user has to only enter the username
but a variable have to catch the whole bb-d-USERNAME

I hope its clearly worded.

Kind regards,
Goeks

Comment: How about `read -p "Enter a username: bb-d-" username` ? Which will prompt `Enter a username: bb-d-` and value `$username` with what the non-fixed part of the username, which you can afterward prepend with the fixed part. (in full : `read -p "Enter a username: bb-d-" username; username="bb-d-$username"`)

Comment: works perfectly thank you very much

Comment: A little concern and a little improvement suggestion : 1) it's not a default value, it's a fixed value ; the user might expect to be able to erase the bb-d- part if he has to enter something else, which he won't be able to ; 2) you should export the fixed part `bb-d-` into a variable so that you only have to change it in one spot instead of two if it comes to change one day : `username_prefix="bb-d-"; read -p "Enter a username : $username_prefix" username; username="$username_prefix$username"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like this,

```
given="bb-d-"
read -p "Enter a user name:"  not_given
complete=$given$not_given
```

`complete` will have the concatenation of both